# Reading closed facebook groups feed through graph api 2.5 , I'm a normal member

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to read a closed facebook group feed that I am a member of. But I get a empty dataset.

In https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog it says:

> "90-day deprecations (effective Tuesday, October 6, 2015)
>   ...
>   the user_groups permission has been deprecated. Developers may continue to use the user_managed_groups permission to access the groups a person is the administrator of. This information is still accessed via the /v2.4/{user_id}/groups edge which is still available in v2.4."

Do I understand this correctly that it's not possible anymore to read a closed groups feed unless I am the admin? Is there any other way to do this? I don't need all the posts, only the posts that user has replied to, and the user replies.

Comment: Using `/{user-id}/groups` only returns groups the user is an admin of, correct. So technically you can still read groups you are an admin of but not all you are a member of.